# Adding user control to 2013 master page causes a 404 error

Tags: 2013, user-controls, custom-masterpage

I have a problem when adding a user control to my SharePoint 2013 master page: my site shows a 404 error.

At this point I have a brand new, empty user control (i.e. created in VS2012 but nothing added other than the content added by default). I'm adding this to my master page as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--SPG:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"[]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" xmlns="" />
    <!--CS: Start Page Head Contents Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register TagPrefix="qmws" TagName="languageSelector" Src="/_controltemplates/langSelector.ascx" %>-->
    <!--SID:00 -->
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" xmlns="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" xmlns="" />
```

The third `<!--SPM:@Register TagPrefix="qmws"...` line is my usercontrol.

- I have verified that the usercontrol is in the `~/_controltemplates` folder.
- I have tried selecting a different out-of-the-box usercontrol from that location (e.g. leftNavigation.ascx) and my pages loads just fine.
- I have tried removing lines from my .ascx page, to match LeftNavigation.ascx, but I still get the 404.
- If I remove that @Register line my page loads correctly.

I'm not sure why this empty usercontrol would cause a problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: In your submitted code you dont have the `~` in `Src="/_controltemplates/langSelector.ascx"`. Is this a type error here or also in your code?

Comment: Both, kinda - but adding that doesn't fix the issue. Thanks for spotting it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2013, to reference the virtual directories you must add /15 after the "_controltemplates" in this case. Like this:

> /_controltemplates/15/langSelector.ascx

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. Here is my new line `<!--SPM:<%@Register TagPrefix="qmws" TagName="languageSelector" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/langSelector.ascx" %>-->` - still gives the 404 error

Comment: Interestingly, this does work (again, using an ootb usercontrol, not my own): `<!--SPM:<%@Register TagPrefix="qmws" TagName="langSelector" Src="/_controltemplates/LeftNavigation.ascx" %>-->` - i.e. without the `/15` you mentioned, and the `~/` mentioned by Daniel in his comment

Comment: @QMKevin That works because SP2013 also installs the SP2010 folders to ensure SP2010=>SP2013 upgrades doesn't ruin the upgraded websites.

Comment: hehe I just got there! I realized I was looking in the `/14` folder when locating my usercontrol, not the `/15`. Copying the usercontrol to `/15/_controltemplates` fixed the issue. Now I need to work out how to get my 'migrated' VS2010 solution to publish to `/15` instead of `/14`, and I'm all set. Thanks both for the help. Credit goes to Robert for pointing me in the direction of `/15`.